# PHP Built-in web server and syntax error in a router script

Tags: php, error-reporting, php-builtin-server

I am using [PHP Built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-449) for testing purposes. For example, with a simple router script:

```php
<?php
echo 'Hello world';
```

Launching it with `php -S localhost:8000 router.php`. Works.

Now, let't say I make a syntax error in the router script (e.g. missing semicolon):

```php
<?php
echo 'Hello world'
```

and launch the dev server with the same command.

Reaching `localhost:8000` in the browser gives me 404 error: *The requested resource / was not found on this server.*. It gives me absolutely no clue about the problem or a syntax error placement. The terminal I lauched the web server in does not show any error (besides 404) either.

I have error reporting set to `E_ALL` in `php.ini`. I have the `display_errors` set to `On`.

Where to look for the error message in such case? How to force PHP to render such errors to the browser instead of a 404 error page?

Comment: Technically, that's not a syntax error. Unless there's more code in the script after that line.

Comment: Are you sure you made the settings in the _correct_ php.ini?

Comment: Yes. Even displayed the `phpinfo()` inside the router script and confirmed the `E_ALL` and `display_errors` are set.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, I came to conclusion that `php-builtin-server` won't log error in any file but directly print to console and send to browser, **but** only if the php file not contains any lexical error. I can't find any documentation on this so feel free to correct me..

A simple work around can be done, check php file lexically  with `php -l` before running `php-builtin-server`. To make things easier, create a batch file for it.

**windows**

create `php-srv.bat` (or any valid name) with content:

```
php -l %1 | find /i "No syntax errors"
if not errorlevel 1 (
   php -S localhost:8000 %1
)
```

execute it with `php-srv route.php`

**linux**

create `php-srv.sh` (or any valid name) with content:

```
if php -l $1 | grep 'No syntax errors detected in'; then
    php -S localhost:8000 $1
fi
```

make it executable with `chmod` and then execute it with `./php-srv.sh route.php`

Hope that's help